# Weird shadows cube raytracing

Tags: c++, raytracing

This is my third question in this raytracing thing, but there's been progress :P So, I'm implementing a C++ ray tracer for my object oriented programming class, and so far I've implemented monochromatic spheres and planes with support to reflection and specular shading. This is an example of a thing I've done:

[image: Whee pretty and shiny]

Now I'm trying to implement general polyhedrons. I'm using a modified version of [this algorithm](http://geomalgorithms.com/a13-_intersect-4.html) to compute intersections with an arbitrary polyhedron of *nFaces()* faces, each of which being contained by a plane defined by *Vec Polyhedron::point(int face)* and *Vec Polyhedron::normal(int face)*:

```
Vec Polyhedron::intersect(Vec o, Vec d)
{
    int face = nFaces();
    Vec ni(0,0,0), pi(0,0,0);
    unit te = -1;
    unit tl = -1;
    unit t = 0;
    unit N, D;
    Vec v = d.normal();
    int facein, faceout;
    for(int i = 0; i < face; i++)
    {
        ni = normal(i);
        pi = point(i);
        N = ((pi - o)*ni);
        D = v*ni;
        if(D == 0 && N < 0)
            return o;
        if(D != 0)
        {
            t = N/D;
            if(t > 0)
            {
                if(N < 0)
                {
                    if(t > te){
                        te = t;
                        facein = i;
                    }
                }else{
                    if((tl == -1) || (t < tl)){
                        tl = t;
                        faceout = i;
                    }
                }
                if((tl != -1) && (tl < te))
                    return o;
            }
        }
    }
    if(tl != -1)
    {
        if(te != -1)
        {
            v = v*te + o;
            return (v + normal(facein)*0.000000000001);
        }
        v = v*tl + o;
        return (v + normal(faceout)*0.000000000001);
    }
    return o;
}
```

So I modified the scene with the balls by removing the balls and adding a red cube (the only type of Polyhedron I implemented was a Cuboid) and ran it. This was the result:

[image]

And I have absolutely no idea why. Any clues?

Comment: I'm confused on what exactly you're doing.  Each face of a polyhedron is defined not only by the plane in which it lies but also its perimeter within that plane.  The typical way of doing this is to intersect the ray with each triangular face; to do that, you first compute the intersection of that ray with the plane in which the triangle lies, and then you test that the intersection point lies inside the triangle.  You seem to be only using the plane of each face and are ignoring everything else.

Comment: Huh. Now that I think of it... I had been under the impression that the (tl < te) part took care of it, but... it really doesn't x) Never mind, I was stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being stupid and misunderstood the algorithm. I thought the (tl < te) part would take care of everything that was on the Polyhedron's face, but it doesn't. Silly me.